# angular material datapicker different format after submit a form

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When I select a data it fills the input with a format like

`DD/MM/YYYY`

but I need to send that data through a form,
when I do a console.log on my component

**datapicker.component.ts**

```
onFindAWhip(form: NgForm){
    const value = form.value;
    console.log(value);
 }
```

I'm getting a full date like

```
Thu Sep 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

> do I have to reformat again ?

it's already done in my DateAdapter, I've tried to get it from here but I just get errors

```
import { NativeDateAdapter }  from '@angular/material';

export class MyDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
   format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {

      let day = date.getDate();
      let month = date.getMonth();
      let year = date.getFullYear();

      if (displayFormat == "input") {


          let pickupData = date.toDateString();
          let pickupDataArray = pickupData.split(" ");
          let yearPicked = pickupDataArray[3]; 

          const without = pickupData.substring(0, pickupData.length-4);

          return without + '     '+yearPicked ;

       } else if (displayFormat == "input-home") {
          return this._to2digit(day) + '/' + this._to2digit(month) +'/'+ year;
       }

       else{
        return date.toDateString();
      }
   }

   private _to2digit(n: number) {
       return ('00' + n).slice(-2);
   }

}
```

**datapicker.html**

```
<span class="calendar-to">
        <button md-raised-button (click)="pickupTo.open()" class="search--icon"></button>
        <input  [mdDatepicker]="pickupTo"
                placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
                name="date_to"
                ngModel>
        <md-datepicker touchUi="true" #pickupTo></md-datepicker>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the ngModel is a DateTime, and includes *all* that information. You will have to process it inside your component.ts if you only want `DD/MM/YYYY`. You can actually just use [Angular's DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) inside your component to quickly and easily do this for you.

import the pipe:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
```

build access:

```
constructor( private datePipe: DatePipe ) { }
```

use in method:

```
onFindAWhip(form: NgForm){
    const value = form.value;
    console.log(this.datePipe.transform(value, 'MM/dd/y'));
 }
```